# Testing "closeness of data"

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have data from two different sets (each with fields named *Mobile* and *Landline*). There are about 5 elements from each field in each set. They go something like so:

Set A:

```
Mobile: 45 61 78 65 71  
Landline: 56 71 75 98 12
```

Set B:

```
Mobile: 67 71 75 64 23  
Landline: 9 34 56 21 22
```

I need to prove/disprove that the figures in the *Mobile* field are closer to the figures in the *Landline* field in *Set A* as against *Set B*. How do I go about doing that? Would a distance measure between the two suffice? If so, what distance measure?

P.S: There may not be enough data in the two sets, but that is all I have at the moment.

***Edit 1***: Here is what I have tried in the interim. I made a single vector out of the `Mobile` and `Landline` scores for `Set A` and did the same for `Set B`. I then compute mean and variance for the two vectors. In case the variance/standard deviation for the vector from `Set A` is lesser than that of `Set B`, I can say that the `Mobile` scores in `Set A` are "closer" to `Landline` scores in `Set A` than `Set B`. Is this approach correct? Why or why not?

Comment: What kind of data are these?  Are they independent samples drawn from the same distribution, or do you expect that the distribution might vary between successive data points, or that they might be correlated?

Comment: @Ilmari: These scores depict the "quality" of a waveform sent over a transmission channel when compared with some "reference" waveform. Since the channel will vary, and the "score" would in some way depend on channel conditions, I would think that the distribution itself might vary between successive data points. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Rahul: stats is not math anymore?

Comment: Stats is math. But question on statistics and data analysis should be asked at stats.stackexchange because you are likely to get much better answers from there (more experts etc.)

Comment: For small data sets, I find it more convincing to simply plot out the numbers. In each set there are 5 data points for landline and for mobile... are these paired data?

Comment: @Ming: I would not say that they are paired. The data was obtained by carrying out tests independently. I dont think they are paired. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @all: I have added some more information in ***Edit 1***. Please take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good distance measure here would be the [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

In the one-dimensional case, the measure simplifies to

$$
\text{distance} = \frac{|\mu_M - \mu_L|}{\sigma_{M+L}}
$$

Here, $\mu_M$ is the mean of the mobile data, $\mu_L$ is the mean of the landline data, and $\sigma_{M+L}$ is the standard deviation of the mobile and landline data combined together.

Running the numbers through from the question, I get
$$
\text{distance}_{\text{Set A}} = \frac{|64.0 - 62.4|}{22.86} = 0.07
$$
$$
\text{distance}_{\text{Set B}} = \frac{|60.0 - 28.4|}{24.81} = 1.27
$$

Basically, this measure is using the spread of the data to normalize the distance between the means.

Answer (score 1):

There are classes of functions known as [f-divergences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) that measure the difference between two probability distributions.  That sort of seems like what you are trying to do, but note that these functions are *not* guaranteed to have the properties of a distance metric (they might not even be symmetrical!).  The [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KL-divergence) is a popular example of an f-divergence.

This might actually be overkill for what you are trying to do, and you might want something a bit more intuitive instead.

**EDIT:**  Upon closer examination of your question, it looks like it probably makes little sense to interpret your particular data in terms of probability distributions, so f-divergences are probably not want you want in this case.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you are asking me to assume that the Mobile and Landline data are samples from an underlying pdf and that measuring the distance between the pdf (via KL etc.) might give me an answer?

Comment: I have added some more information. Please take a look at that too. Thanks!

Comment: @Sriam Yes I was saying that, but when thinking about it more I think converting the data into a probability distribution might be a bit weird in this instance...not sure...

Answer (score 1):

**My proposal**

For each set calculate:

- |min(Mobile)-min(Landline)|
- |max(Mobile)-max(Landline)|
- |mean(Mobile)-mean(Landline)| (alternative: median)

This approach measures only how close the intervals are to each other.

Then you have one vector for each set. Now the difference of sets can be calculated by using e.g. Euclidean Distance.

**Regarding Edit1**

Yes, this is certainly a way to go. Two remarks:

- Maybe instead of performing a "is-smaller"-test you may want to calculate the euclidean difference between the variances of both sets. This way you have a measure of the increase of quality
- Note that by using the variance of the union of Mobile and Landline you are not only measuring how close Mobile and Landline are to each other but also how the variances of Mobile and Landline are *respectively*.

The second point marks the difference to my proposal. If Mobile and Landline contains data in the interval [0,100] (i.e. 0 and 100 are occuring too), my proposal will lead to the vector(0,0,0) which represents a perfect match, however, the variance of Mobile and Landline *respectively* is way too high, hence the matching is trivially correct but useless.

One the other hand, if the variance in Mobile and/or Landline is fixed, I suggest to use my proposal to focus entirely on the closeness of the intervals.

**General hint:** If you create a metric, always check how to game it. Then ask yourself whether the imagined situation can actually happen or not.

Answer (score 1):

What is the significance of the numbers ? If they represent some kind of quantity that admits a distance (i.e it makes sense to say that 54 is "closer" to 55 than to 56), then you could use the earthmover distance.

Comment: What is meant by "significance"? Also, these scores are computed with reference to a score of 100 (golden). So 55 would be equi-distant from 54 and 56, though I would say that 56 is better than 54.

Comment: I mean, what is the actual meaning of the numbers - what do they represent in your original application.

Comment: They represent scores - that measure the quality of a speech signal obtained over a landline/mobile to a "golden" recording. The scores are computed by a non-linear function that takes some features as parameter (cannot go into more detail).